# "Phishing Attack Ahead" warning on Apple Mail link preview

Tags: phishing

I received a suspicious email and moved it to my spam folder. I kept getting the same email so I blocked the sender.

I got curious about the link in it and pressed the dropdown arrow on Mac mail to preview the link. It was my understanding this doesn't actually open the link.

The preview showed a red page with a Phishing Attack Ahead warning from PixelMe.

- I didn't actually open the link on my browser.
- I ran an Avast scan and came out clean.

I am worried if I should do something else to be safe or if am I being paranoid. I am very involved in the crypto world and I'm aware of how many threats there are.

I've attached screenshots of the email, the dropdown, and the preview.

[image: Email][image][image: Phishing Alert]

Answer (score 1):

A phishing attack is defined as such:

> the fraudulent practice of sending emails or other messages purporting to be from reputable companies in order to induce individuals to reveal personal information, such as passwords and credit card numbers.

If you did not enter any of your personal detailed or credentials into the link in the email, and you are up to date with all your software, you are most likely safe.